# How to handle database connection exception globally in springboot application?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, exception, connectionexception

I have a springboot + postgres application.
I want to handle database failure exception globally and need to store request in file system.
Is there any way in springboot application to catch ConnectionException globally?

Comment: What do you mean by "need to store request in file system"?

Comment: i need to handle connection exception and store httprequest from controller to some text file.

Comment: "store httprequest from controller to some text file" - you mean log it? and to handle failure `@ExceptionHandler`? this is basic spring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

   import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
   import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

   @Provider
   public class ExceptionHandler  implements ExceptionMapper<ConnectionException > {
  
  @Override
  public Response toResponse(Exception exception) {
    //insert code here
    return Response.ok().build();
  }
}
```